# The number of products with two even integers giving $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*Premises:* Let $c(n)$ denote the number of products of the form
    $$ n = a \cdot b $$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive even integers and $a < b$.

*Conjecture:* If $4$ divides $n$ then
   $$  c(n) = \Bigl\lfloor \frac{\tau(n/4)}{2} \Bigr\rfloor , $$
where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

*Example:* Let $n=24$, then the products with two parts (disregarding the
order) which are divisors of $n$ are
     $$ 1 \cdot 24,\ 2 \cdot 12,\ 3 \cdot 8,\ 4 \cdot 6. $$
Those with even integers only are $\{2, 12\}$ and $\{4, 6\}.$
Also 
    $$ \lfloor \tau(24/4)/2 \rfloor = \tau(6)/2 = 4/2 = 2, $$
as predicted.

Comment: Is there a question??

Comment: Of course: Is there a proof for the conjecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each decomposition $n = ab$ (where $a< b$ are both even) corresponds with a unique 
decomposition $n/4 = (a/2)(b/2)$ (where $a/2 < b/2$) of $n/4$.

The number of such decompositions of $n/4$ situation is $\lfloor \tau(n/4)/2\rfloor$ (specifically it is $\tau(n/4)/2$ if $n/4$ is not a perfect square, and $(\tau(n/4)-1)/2$ if $n/4$ is a perfect square).